# Parse HTML table using AngleSharp

Tags: c#, html, parsing, anglesharp

Can't get the content from a HTML table.

```
var Parser = new HtmlParser();
var Document = Parser.Parse(Source);

var Items = Document.QuerySelectorAll("table#mytable tbody tr td");

Console.WriteLine(Items);
```

> AngleSharp.Dom.Collections.HtmlCollection`1[AngleSharp.Dom.IElement]

```
foreach (var Item in Items)
{
   Console.WriteLine(Item);
}
```

> No output

Comment: have you something in Document? so if yes your queryselectorall is not right. It will be interesting to see the Source and describe exactly what you want to find..because i am not sure you could use the queryselectorall as you do.

Comment: Yes, Document has content.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the table with the name 'mytable'? Make sure you have HTML content in Source. Because I don't find anything wrong in the code otherwise.

Comment: The table is generated dynamically on the browser side. So it did not appear in Source. This was the issue. Thank you for the clue